# Batch-Script check second line and do case-sensitive task

Tags: windows, batch

I was working on a tool using Lazarus IDE which starts external batch scripts to do things (I've been told that I can implement those things in Lazarus itself but I'm sticking with Batch scripts since I can change them in the future if I need to). Some config-entries are written to a `.ini`-file.

For example I have two scripts for two different languages (let's call them `english.bat` and `german.bat`). With a TButton in Lazarus it changes the entry in my `.ini` file and then starts a Batch file called `changeLang.bat` and this is where I need help.

My `changeLang.bat` should check the entry in my `.ini` file (there is a line (line 3) which either says `lang=ger` or `lang=eng`) and start the respective script (if `lang=ger` start `german.bat` / if `lang=eng` start `english.bat`).

The only Problem I have is I'm not sure how to read the third line in my `.ini` file and set the conditions for both cases. I set up a script but it says syntax-error when starting the batch-file via cmd. This is my code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" conf.ini')

case lang=deu
    start german.bat
    GOTO END_CASE
    
case lang=eng
    start english.bat
    GOTO END_CASE

rem case thrid_option
rem    start thid_option.bat
rem    GOTO END_CASE

:END_CASE
    exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'm not sure how to read the third line in my .ini file

Note that there is no `case` statement in batch files.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('findstr "lang=" conf.ini') do (
  echo %%G
  if "%%G"=="eng" (
    start english.bat
    goto :done
    )
  if "%%G"=="ger" (
    start german.bat
    )
    goto :done
  )
  :done
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [For /f - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: First of all thank you for answering. I tried this but it doesn't start the other batch-script. I tried executing the script with cmd itself and it did echo the right output but no script is getting started.

Comment: Answer updated to fix a quoting error

Comment: Ah yes, it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

**[`if(condition) else if(condition) else(condition)`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

```bat
@echo off && setlocal

for /f tokens^=2delims^=^= %%i in ('%__AppDir__%Findstr.exe "lang=" ^<.\conf.ini
   ')do echo=%%~i & if /i "%%~i"=="eng" (echo=call .\english.bat && goto:eng
        )else if /i "%%~i"=="deu" (echo=call .\german.bat && goto:ger
            )else echo\call .\thid_option.bat && goto:3rd
    
echo=If you see this message something has already gone wrong^!!
endlocal & goto :eof 

:eng
echo\I'm in :eng
rem. :: your code ... & endlocal & goto :eof

:ger
echo\I'm in :ger
rem. :: your code ... & endlocal & goto :eof

:3rd
echo\I'm in :3rd
rem. :: your code ... & endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

Or using **`Findstr`** with operator  **`&&  ||`**:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal

%__AppDir__%Findstr.exe /i "lang=eng" .\conf.ini >nul && (goto :eng) || (
     %__AppDir__%Findstr.exe /i "lang=deu" .\conf.ini >nul && goto :ger) || goto:3rd
    
:eng
echo\I'm in :eng
rem. :: your code ... & endlocal & goto :eof

:ger
echo\I'm in :ger
rem. :: your code ... & endlocal & goto :eof

:3rd
echo\I'm in :3rd
rem. :: your code ... & endlocal & goto :eof
```

- **Obs.:** Make sure there is no space/tab (or any invisible character) after the strings in your ini file, in the "`lang=eng`".